# How to implement application updates?

Tags: android

I would like to let users download new updates of my APP (if such exist) and not really sure how is it done. I mean if 100 users install my APP and later they find some bug in it, i would like to download them a new pack or something. could anyone suggest the best pratice to achive it.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got your app on Android Market, you just publish an update and users will be notified of the update the next time they vist Android Market.

If you're not on the Android Market you need to make sure the application has a "conversation" with your server so that the server can tell the app it needs to be updated.

Comment: thank you, but what i really wanted to know is how to upload user not the whole apk but just some part of it..i am not familiar with updates...

Comment: AFAIK you are not able to release updates to part of the apk and get it to rebuild on the client phone. You need to update the entire application package.

Answer (score 0):

Just build the new app with the **modified versionName & versionCode (in manifest file)**
See this in your manifest

```
android:versionName="1.0"
 android:versionCode="1"
```

Update this and publish the updated app on the android market. User will be notified if he has selected the checkbox for automatic update for that app in the android market.

Make sure that you use the same signing key cerificate while publishiing the updated app.